# Message box appears multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

With my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Set Target = Me.Range("D10", "D17")
 Dim KeyCells As Range
 Set KeyCells = Range("D10", "D17")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("D10").Value < 31.35 Then
     Ans = msgbox("The accumulated Rain fall for this week is insuficient." & vbNewLine & "Click Yes if it was irrigated" & vbNewLine & "Click No if not", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Rainfall Insufficient")


    End If
End If

Select Case Ans
            Case vbYes
               Range("E10").Value = "Yes"
                Exit Sub
            Case vbNo
                Range("E10").Value = "No"
                Exit Sub
          End Select



End Sub
```

the message box appears multiple times but when I comment the `Select Case` it disappears.

Why?

Comment: Could you please re-upload the code and explain what your trying to do.

Comment: Whenever you change a cell on the sheet where you're tracking changes, you typically would call `Application.EnableEvents = False` *before* making the change(s).  Don't forget to set it back to `True` when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems. I'll detail what I think the issues are and then make a suggestion as to the correct rewrite.

1. `Set Target = Me.Range("D10", "D17")` is wrong. **Target** gets passed into the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro as the cell or cells that have received new values, had their values modified or had their values deleted. It is your key as to what cells have changed and setting Target to something else destroys that.
2. `If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then` makes no sense if you just set **Target** to the same range as the **KeyCells** var. Of course they are going to intersect. They are the same thing.
3. `Select Case Ans` If the If statement containing the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) can be repaired, this [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) belongs **inside** the If Intersect Then statement.
4. `Set KeyCells = Range("D10", "D17")` Typically, I never declare, assign or set anything until I know I am going to need it. Like the Select Case, this belongs inside the If Intersect Then statement.
5. `Range(Target.Address)` If we leave Target alone (see #1 above) then this is the same as saying `Target`.
6. As mentioned in a couple of places, if you plan to change values on the worksheet, you need to turn events off with `Application.EnableEvents = False` or you will trigger another event and the macro will try to run on top of itself.

This is my best guess at what you were trying for.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D10", "D17"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim ans As Long, KeyCells As Range

        Set KeyCells = Range("D10", "D17")   '<~~ this is completely unnecessary now.

        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            If Range("D10").Value < 31.35 Then
                ans = MsgBox("The accumulated Rain fall for this week is insuficient." & vbNewLine & _
                             "Click Yes if it was irrigated" & vbNewLine & _
                             "Click No if not", _
                             vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Rainfall Insufficient")
                Select Case ans
                    Case vbYes
                       Range("E10").Value = "Yes"
                    Case vbNo
                        Range("E10").Value = "No"
                End Select
            End If
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D17"), Target) Is Nothing Then

            'do something for when it was D17 that changed here

        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You will probably want to do something with the area I left when D17 received a change. Do not exit the sub without turning the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) back on or all event macros will cease to 'trigger'.

Answer (score -1):

Worksheet_Change event happens on the change of cell selection.

your select case edit value for range(E10), so worksheet_change event happens again, and it becomes recursive call on the event handling.

Comment: The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro is triggered by a chane in value to one or more cells on a worksheet. You are thinking of the [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event macro.